# Интернет и Delphi

Tags: delphi

Задание: любым способом **прочесть** файл из Интернета.
Т.е. нужно использовать файл из интернета (по уже существующему адресу) (любой - например открыть БД) без его скачивания из Сети. Т.е. не скаичать на жестянку,а сразу открыть.

Возможен FTP и всё остальное.

Comment: Что значит "без скачивания"?) Украсть хард, яхз)) 

ЗЫ: по FTP процесс получения файла тоже называется скачиванием. Без сохранения на хард - то же самое, что с сохранением на хард, только используя TMemoryStream вместо TFileStream.

Comment: как без сохранения на хард?

Comment: Если вы "прочитали файл из интернета", он уже в любом случае скачан к вам на компьютер. В память, или на винт - дело пятое.

Answer (score 5):

Откройте для себя [этот сайт](http://delphisources.ru/pages/faq.html), а конкретно сейчас эту [страницу](http://delphisources.ru/pages/faq/internet_net.html), раздел "Файлы и Интернет", там штук 6 вариантов скачивания. Если и так не понятно - ищем, как работать с TMemoryStream на том же сайте.

А если вам надо **открыть** его, типа "скачать текстовик и открыть блокнотом", то в любом случае надо его скачивать во временную директорию, которую очищать при выходе, и запускать файл, через createProcess или еще как, это уже ваше дело.